# What is the use of declaring a user defined type constant with null value?

Tags: c#, types, reference, constants

```
public class TestClass
{
    const MyType SOMECONSTANT = null;

    protected string TestString { get; set; }    
}

public class MyType
{
    protected string FieldA { get; set; }
}
```

The above code is valid and it compiles. Why does C# allow a reference type `const` with `null`? How can I use this `SOMECONSTANT` as this is going to be `null` always?

Comment: I suppose because null is a valid value that can be assigned to reference types and nullable values types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it could used as a placeholder that will at a some point later in the development cycle hold an instance of the specified object. Generally constants are used as something to compare against. Taking that idea and assuming that programmer B is going to implement and instantiate the object PERFECT_TYPE later you could say something like

```
const MyType PERFECT_TYPE = null;
```

and later I might have

```
if (myInstance.Equals(TestClass.PERFECT_TYPE)) { /*do stuff*/ }
```

Although in this situation I'd point out you'd need an implementation of `MyType.Equals()` but you get the idea. Things like this are not uncommon in stubbing, particularly in agile development. I would say that a stub would be more likely to be a property than a constant but, each tool for its purpose...